# vue 2 project doesn't enable hot loading

Tags: vuejs2

my vue project doesn't enable hot load, here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "vue-tailwind-admin",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "clipboard": "^2.0.6",
    "core-js": "^3.6.4",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "node-sass": "^6.0.1",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-router": "^3.1.5",
    "vuedraggable": "^2.24.1",
    "vuex": "^3.1.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^4.2.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^4.2.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^4.2.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.8.8",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.1.2",
    "postcss": "^7.0.39",
    "sass-loader": "^10.2.0",
    "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat@^2.2.17",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    },
    "rules": {
      "no-unused-vars": "off"
    }
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions"
  ]
}
```

I have no idea what goes wrong, please help

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try to use this way
https://github.com/vuejs/vuepress/issues/2392

1. check your node versiton >= 12.14
2. check your watchpack versiton >= 1.6.1

and you can description more details plz.